# How do you handle command side-affects in a CQRS architecture?

Tags: domain-driven-design, distributed, cqrs

We are beginning to find a few scenarios in our system whereby the result of a command against an aggregate can affect other related aggregates.

To demonstrate the problem, consider a tree structure where we have nodes which have siblings. Each node has a ranking to determine the order in which they are displayed in the UI i.e.

```
Node 1 | Ranking = 10
Node 2 | Ranking = 11
Node 3 | Ranking = 12
Node 4 | Ranking = 13
Node 5 | Ranking = 14
```

Our Node aggregate has an invariant which dictates that rankings cannot be set below a specific value (lets call it 10). If a ranking is set below this value it causes a recalculation of *all* sibling nodes (including the node in question). For simplicities sake, say the calculation simply works out the ranking based on double the prev siblings ranking

```
Node 1 | Ranking = 9 (cannot be accepted, reset to 50)
Node 2 | Ranking = 100
Node 3 | Ranking = 200
Node 4 | Ranking = 400
Node 5 | Ranking = 800
```

The point is, a command against one aggregate results in a change to another aggregate (or multiple in this case).

The approach taken so far for this is to intercept these commands on the way to the domain, "fix" them and *then* send them. So in the above example scenario

- We receive a `ChangeNodeRankingCommand` from the client
- We validate the command i.e. is it new ranking above 10
- If the command is valid it's sent to the domain
- If the command is not valid, we query the read side to pull out all affected aggregate Ids
- We create a command for each aggregate (including the one in question) with the adjusted ranking
- We send those commands to the domain and discard the original

This works fine, however, there are some concerns

- We are always working with stale data which can lead to problems (attemping to update an entity which is subsequently removed etc.)
- This stuff *appears* to be domain logic and as such should probably be dealt with by the domain

The reason for opting to do it this way is purely from a querying point of view, we use [Event Sourcing](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventSourcing.html) in our domain therefore loading related aggregate's isn't trivial (given the nature of our event store).

Is this a reasonable approach or am I completely missing a trick here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first glance (given that the node/ranking stuff is most likely simplified) it appears that your aggregate boundary for the "ranking" attribute may be mis-placed, in particular if the ranking of one node affects the ranking of its siblings, which is clearly crossing AR boundaries.

In a typical tree structure (in the mathematical sense), the *parent* of all the siblings may be considered to be responsible for the ordering of its children.  In this model, if you then send a `ChangeNodeRankingCommand` to the parent of those children, the re-ranking of all the children takes place within on AR.

If "ranking" has a more complex meaning, you can try to de-couple the ordering in the parent node from the "ranking" attribute of the individual nodes with a saga (i.e., send a re-ordering command whenever the ranking changes).

Comment: I had an inkling that this approach wasn't correct (hence the question). So instead of having a separate command for each Node aggregate, fire a *single* command to the parent e.g. `CalculateChildRankingsCommand` and perform this in the domain? That does make sense, the only downside is my current setup doesn't allow for that type of query on the write-side. Effectively, I would need to load *every* Node and then filter by parent - I guess that's more of a design problem though.

Comment: Yes, that would be what I meant. As for the query problem, you can of course also use a projection for that.

Comment: When you say I can use a projection for that do you mean have the write-side query the read side? Or actually have projections created on the write-side? I'm new to the whole CQRS game and the biggest problem I find is there aren't any clearly defined rules for that type of stuff. Currently my domain can only load an aggregate in isolation (it can't load related aggregates).

Comment: If your parent node needs to have a list of or some information on all of its children nodes to perform its action, you can, for example, add a domain service interface to your domain layer that lets the parent node query for the necessary information.  This domain layer can then be implemented (out of the domain layer, just as repositories) by a read model (backed by a projection), such that this query is fast and doesn't require involved queries.

Comment: So this domain service would query the read side? Isn't that the same issue I was talking about earlier where by querying the read side means you are (potentially) working with stale data? "*a read model (backed by a projection)*" I'm *sort of* getting confused now, isn't a read model / projection the same thing?

Comment: Yes, this only solves the cross-AR-boundary issue.  If a stale read model is a problem (i.e., you *always* need to query the DB anyways to get the most recent data), you may want keep all the necessary information in one AR.

Comment: A read model is the "read side" in the CQRS model.  A "projection" is a (partial) snapshot of the current state of the event stream when using event sourcing.  When doing CQRS+ES, one usually projects the stream of events into the read model.

Comment: "*one usually projects a stream of events into the read model*" - that's what I am currently doing, however, it's not a synchronous process so there is always a chance that state changes as we are querying. This can have implications, for example, if I wanted to delete a node and all of it's nodes children. I would need to query the read-side for a list of child ids, however, say during that query a new node was added and I have now gone and removed the parent....I have orphaned that node. I guess if consistency is a problem then they probably *should* all be under the same AR

Comment: However, it could get messy trying to store an entire structure as a single record in the write-side. I think for now I can go with the domain service querying the read-side, thanks for your help & advice :)